# how can i shorten my imports as import xxx from "@dir/subdir/file" in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have configured my `jsconfig.json` in my root directory as:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@dir/*": ["./src/app/dir/*"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"],
}
```

my folder structure looks as follows:

```
root  
│
└───src
│   |__app
|   |    |__dir 
|   |    |    |__subdir1 
|   |    |    |     |__file1.js and other js files
|   |    |    |__subdir2
|   |    |          |__file2.js
|
|__jsconfig.json
|__package.json
|__...other root files
```

my goal is to import something from file 1 to file 2 using

```
import xyz from '@dir/subdir1/file1'
```

instead of using

```
import xyz from '../subdir1/file1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your webpack config `webpack.config.js` eventually has:

For CRA after ejecting your webpack config, you should be able to navigate to `webpack.config.js` and add your alias to the list.

```
 resolve {
     alias: {
       "@dir": "src/app/dir"
    },
 }
```

or in Next.js `next.config.js`

```
 config.resolve.alias = {
   ...config.resolve.alias,
   "@dir": "src/app/dir"
};
```

Check out this documentation: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/

Comment: how do i do that given i created my app using CRA?

Comment: try `npm run eject` in the root directory of your app

Answer (score 0):

You can use this babel plugin: https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver